# Mysql Insert data weekly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where by there is a person and his/her weekly payments.
Each person is supposed to have paid a certain amount let's say 100,000. 
If (s)he fail to reach 100,000 then it carry on to the next week. 
If (s)he passes 100,000 then it reduces the next week amount by the balance passed on.
Week start at Saturday.

I was thinking of having a design like this. I know it's wrong. So help me on this
[image: my rough design]

**Update**
Also I need to mark if this user has paid his dues for this week. So there is some sort of status to keep.
I have come to realize maybe I can implement it using this

```
SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, "2010-01-04")/7, 0) AS weeksout
```

That's means I can have a start counting date and use that my index in the payment table like this.

**Weeks**

```
-->id
-->week_no
-->start_date
-->end_date
```

**Payments**

```
-->id
-->person_id
-->week_no
-->amount
-->date
```

**Payment_status**

```
-->person_id
-->week_no
-->status
-->balance
-->carry
```

Using the Payment_status I can keep track of the week status(Paid, Not Paid, Partial Paid).
I am still not comfortable with this, I don't know why.

Comment: Do insert stmts only. No updates. This thing must be Sarbanes Oxley compliant afterall :p

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: Its a valid nth normalized structure.  You can do it without the weeks table if you rely on date calculations.  My guess would be you might want to consider a date dimmension (plenty of documentation out there) because you might have other uses beyond just week, such as looking at quarterly or yearly balance etc.

Comment: How can I do that? @Matt

Answer (score 0):

I THINK YOU CAN GO WITH FOLLOWING TABLE STRUCTURE

```
PERSON (ID,NAME,...,weekly_payment_amount)
PAYMENT (YEAR,MONTH,WEEK,PERSON_ID,AMOUNT);
```

FOR EACH WEEK YOU WILL HAVE A ENTRY FOR ALL PERSON IN PAYMENTS TABLE
FOR THAT WEEK PERIOD IF PERSON COULDN'T COMPLETE HIS TARGET HE WILL HAVE 0 AMOUNT FOR THAT WEEK AND COMPLETED AMOUNT WILL BE ADDED TO NEXT WEEK
IF HE COMPLETE ADDITIONAL AMOUNT FOR UPCOMING WEEK IT WILL ADD A ENTRY WITH ADDITIONAL PART

WHEN YOUR INSERTING NEW ENTRY DO IT IN FOLLOWING WAY YOU HAVE TO handle some logics form code level

```
$AMOUNT = WORKED AMOUNT FOR THIS WEEK

CHECK IF ANY VALUE AVALABLE FOR THAT WEEK

$AMOUNT_EXP= SELECT weekly_payment_amount FROM PERSON WHERE PERSON_ID ="";
$AMOUNT_ADD= SELECT IFNULL(AMOUNT,0) AS FROM PAYMENT WHERE YEAR="" AND MONTH="" AND WEEK="" AND PERSON_ID ="";

IF ($AMOUNT_ADD>0) THEN {
    IF $AMOUNT_EXP> $AMOUNT_ADD+ $AMOUNT THEN {

        UPDATE PAYMENT SET  AMOUNT= 0 WHERE YEAR="", MONTH="", WEEK="", PERSON_ID ="";
        INSERT INTO PAYMENT(YEAR,MONTH,WEEK,PERSON_ID,AMOUNT) VALUES (<YEAR,MONTH,WEEK FOR NEXT WEEK>,$AMOUNT_ADD+ $AMOUNT);
    } 
    ELSE {
        UPDATE PAYMENT SET  AMOUNT=$AMOUNT_EXP  WHERE YEAR="", MONTH="", WEEK="", PERSON_ID ="";
        INSERT INTO PAYMENT(YEAR,MONTH,WEEK,PERSON_ID,AMOUNT) VALUES (<YEAR,MONTH,WEEK FOR NEXT WEEK>,($AMOUNT_ADD+ $AMOUNT)-$AMOUNT_EXP);
    }

}
ELSE {
     IF $AMOUNT_EXP> $AMOUNT_ADD+ $AMOUNT THEN {

        INSERT INTO PAYMENT(YEAR,MONTH,WEEK,PERSON_ID,AMOUNT) VALUES (<YEAR,MONTH,WEEK FOR CURRENT WEEK>,0);
        INSERT INTO PAYMENT(YEAR,MONTH,WEEK,PERSON_ID,AMOUNT) VALUES (<YEAR,MONTH,WEEK FOR NEXT WEEK>,$AMOUNT_ADD+ $AMOUNT);
    } 
    ELSE {
        UPDATE PAYMENT SET  AMOUNT=$AMOUNT_EXP  WHERE YEAR="", MONTH="", WEEK="", PERSON_ID ="";
        INSERT INTO PAYMENT(YEAR,MONTH,WEEK,PERSON_ID,AMOUNT) VALUES (<YEAR,MONTH,WEEK FOR NEXT WEEK>,($AMOUNT_ADD+ $AMOUNT)-$AMOUNT_EXP);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put insert and select queries of your solutions?

Comment: I want mysql only, not more than that.